# DLL only containing code in DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH missing from executable dependencies?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, dll, dll-injection

I've got a DLL injection based project that I'm looking to test locally. In the target environment the DLL is loaded via AppInit_DLLs, which means it's loaded at approximately the same time user32.dll is loaded when a process is first executed. All of this works, the DLL creates a log file demonstrating success.

I'm now looking to test the behavior of the DLL in a controlled environment, specifically within the context of a test win32 program I've created in Visual Studio 2015. I took the generated lib file from the DLL project and added it as an additional dependency under Project Settings -> Linker -> Input, added the directory containing that lib file to VC++ Directories -> Library Directories and placed the DLL file alongside the generated executable. When I run the executable, however, I do not see my log file.

I decided to investigate further using dependency walker, and I don't see any mention of my DLL, so it would appear that the dependency was never added.

Some additional information:

- Both are built using the same target architecture
- The win32 test application is built using /MDd (Multi-threaded debug DLL)
- The test application does not use any exported functions from the DLL, since all I'm seeking to test is that the code executed in DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH does the right thing

I can test using a separate injection process to create a thread in the remote test process, but I'm looking to replicate the behavior of the DLL being loaded early in process execution, so this alternative is not ideal.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks :-)

Comment: add any exported function in dll and import this function in exe. place lib for dll at first place in lib order. this give you ~ (but not exactly) case

Comment: The linker does a dependency analysis on .lib files, those that aren't needed aren't linked.  True for both import libraries and static libraries.  The fact that self-registration (dependent on a constructor of a global object) doesn't work with .lib files is very well-known.  Your case is similar.

Comment: Success! Thank you, in retrospect it makes perfect sense that it would be optimized out.

Comment: *"I'm seeking to test is that the code executed in DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH does the right thing"* - For most practical purposes, that code shouldn't be doing anything (see [Dynamic-Link Library Best Practices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn633971.aspx)). Besides, the question title doesn't describe the problem, and half of the question text is redundant back story, unrelated to the issue. A bit of an overhaul would do no harm.

Comment: I'm aware of DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH best practices. I'm using it to hook low-level functions.

Furthermore, the issue I wanted help with wasn't finding out if the code is doing the right thing, but rather why the DLL wasn't being loaded. Also, I do believe the backstory was what provided RbMb with the information required to quickly assess and answer the question.

Comment: No, it wasn't. Had you written a 3-sentence question, explaining that you were trying to link against a DLL, but aren't actually importing anything from it, and that DLL doesn't get loaded, it would have been sufficient. And the title is still a mile off. The question is not at all about DLL injection.

Comment: I'll agree with you that the title could be changed now that I understand the issue (and accordingly I have done so), but I still don't believe that providing as much information as I did was in error. Which details are most relevant are clearer in hindsight, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RbMm's answer was correct. The issue was that the DLL was not being linked as it was not being used. Adding an exported method and calling it in the test program did the trick.